# Who killed these characters in "Deathly Hallows"?

Tags: harry-potter

My question is what happened to

> Remus Lupin and his wife Tonks?

Who killed them?

I watched the movies and also read the books but I didn't understand that part.

Comment: Bellatrix killed Tonks _after a super close fight_ :)

Comment: Ohh, sorry I just wanted the answer and I got that but how to close this question? Please can u tell me?

Comment: You can leave it open- it'll just be labelled as a "duplicate".

Comment: Will it affect my rep?

Comment: No, it will not. You should read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question

Comment: And I personally think it would be better to change the headline of the question.

Comment: @AmanRaizada No, there's nothing inherently wrong with duplicate questions. You should get a box suggesting there's an answer on the other question, along with the option to confirm that it did answer your question; confirming that will close it as a duplicate without requiring more people to vote to close.

Comment: Okk thanks and I edited it's title. Is it okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Antonin Dolohov and Bellatrix Lestrange, respectively

This is not stated in the books, but Rowling answers this in an [interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html).

> Casey Kunze: **Who killed Remus and Tonks** I think if I knew this, I would get some closure over the very sad, but understandable, death of two of my favorite characters
>
> J.K. Rowling: I'm so sorry! I met a couple on launch night who had come dressed as Lupin and Tonks, and I felt dreadfully guilty as I signed their books!
>
> **J.K. Rowling: Remus was killed by Dolohov and Tonks by Bellatrix.**

Also stated in Pottermore (credits to Gallifreyan):

> Remus was no longer in prime fighting condition when he rushed to join the fight. Months of inactivity, using mostly spells of concealment and protection, had blunted his duelling capabilities, and when he ran up against a dueller of Dolohov’s skill, now battle-hardened after months of killing and maiming, his reactions were too slow.

Comment: Remus' killer is also confirmed on his [Pottermore page](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/remus-lupin) (at the bottom).